# ERROR Uncaught exception in REST call to /favicon.ico (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper:61)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am getting the below favicon.ico error for the Kafka source connectors. Anyone have an idea how to fix it, that would be a great help.
It loads lacks or thousands of records from oracle to Cassandra using Kafka connector. We restarted the connectors and Kafka server but still issue not resolved.

Source connector properties:

```
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
"timestamp.column.name": "UPDT_TS",
"transforms.createKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
"connection.password": "${file:/usr/local/kafka/kafka/secret.properties:oraPassword}",
"tasks.max": "1",
"query": "select sys_id||'-'||sales_org||'-'||brand||'-'||product||'-'||mat_num||'-'||country||'-'||plant as \"id\", sys_id as \"sys_id\",sales_org as \"sales_org\",brand as \"brand\",product as \"product\",mat_num as \"mat_num\",country as \"country\",plant as \"plant\",apo_ind as \"apo_ind\",to_char(availability_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as \"availability_date\",base_unit_of_msr as \"base_unit_of_msr\",to_char(created_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as \"created_date\",to_char(unrest_use_stock) as \"unrest_use_stock\",to_char(updt_ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as \"updt_ts2\",updt_ts FROM availability",
"connection.attempts": "10000",
"transforms": "createKey,extractInt",
"transforms.extractInt.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
"batch.max.rows": "3000",
"timestamp.delay.interval.ms": "120000",
"table.types": "query",
"mode": "timestamp",
"topic.prefix": "avail_topic2",
"tables": "",
"transforms.extractInt.field": "id",
"task.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask",
"schema.pattern": "",
"transforms.createKey.fields": "id",
"connection.user": "${file:/usr/local/kafka/kafka/secret.properties:oraUsername}",
"poll.interval.ms": "10000",
"name": "jdbc_avail_connector",
"connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@****:***"`
```

Recently it is not loading any data we seeing the below error in the logs.

```
ERROR Uncaught exception in REST call to /favicon.ico (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper:61)
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect REST API has no favicon. If you are loading the API in a browser, then the brower will automatically request a favicon.ico file, however, this doesn't cause a connector to stop/fail, so the error is elsewhere

For example, you should check the `/status` endpoint of your connector

Comment: I verified the status it is running status only, I restarted both source and sink connectors then i am seeing the data is moving to Kafka.
But the problem is whenever this favicon error comes in the logs, source data is not moving to Kafka we need to restart connectors manually. is there any way to fix this problem without restarting manually?